# Trying to make a prediction on a csv file using data from another

Tags: python

I followed a few tutorials but I keep getting the same error. I don't know what to do anymore. I'm trying to use the data in HealthScores to inform the Population file on how to grade the people's health scores. I'd appreciate some help to fix the errors i get :None of [Index(['Health Score(high is good)'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

```
hs = pd.read_csv('HealthScores.csv')
pop = pd.read_csv('Population.csv')

pop['Health Score(high is good)'] = hs[['Health Score(high is good)']].shift(-predicted_Hscore)

hs_train, hs_test, pop_train, pop_test = train_test_split(hs, pop, test_size = 0.25)

#tree 

tree = DecisionTreeRegressor().fit(hs_train, pop_train)

#linear regression

lr =LinearRegression().fit(hs_train,pop_train)

pred_Score = hs.drop(['Health Score(high is good)'], 1)[:-predicted_Hscore]

pred_Score = pred_Score.tail(predicted_Hscore)

pred_Score = np.array(pred_Score)

pred_Score

tree_prediction = tree.predict(pred_Score)
print(tree_prediction)

lr_prediction = lr.predict(pred_Score)
print (lr_prediction)
```

Comment: 1. Please use backticks ` to insert code blocks, not single quotes. 2. Please include more information as to what you are trying to accomplish and maybe even the error you are getting could help?

Comment: oh sorry. my bad

Comment: According to your error `'Health Score(high is good)'` is not a colum in either `pop` or `hs`. You can print the columns with `pop.columns`.

Comment: but that's impossible cause I've already used this column to make various charts. The column is there for sure. I just checked and it is indeed there

Comment: Have you printed the columns as @ygorg said? E.g., `print(pop.columns)`. Ditto for `hs`.

Comment: Yes I have printed them. I don't know what is wrong honestly. It might be the logic I'm using?

Comment: It appears that the problem is coming from

pop['Health Score(high is good)'] = hs[['Health Score(high is good)']].shift(-predicted_Hscore). 

If anyone has any ideas I would really appreciate it